# CakePhp How to load multiple context in create form in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form that affects multiple models, but when a model fails validation I want to send error messages to the form.

If I create a form like this `$this->Form->create($context)` works, how can I pass multiple contexts so that my form shows me all errors from all models?

Comment: Post more of your code

Comment: If the models are all associated, and you have a single entity with the entire structure in place, then using that entity as the context will generate all the error messages as you are expecting.